# How to redirect to particular page after Azure AD Login?

Tags: azure-active-directory

I am integrating Azure AD login in my application. I want to redirect to particular action after successful azure ad login. I have a below code in my Startup.Auth.cs file. But it is not redirecting to redirecturi. Anyone can suggest me how to redirect to a custom page after successful login.

```
public static void ConfigureAuth(IAppBuilder app)
        {
            app.UseKentorOwinCookieSaver();
            app.UseCookieAuthentication(new CookieAuthenticationOptions());
            app.SetDefaultSignInAsAuthenticationType(CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationType);
            app.UseOpenIdConnectAuthentication(
                new OpenIdConnectAuthenticationOptions
                {
                    ClientId = clientId,
                    Authority = authority,
                    PostLogoutRedirectUri = postLogoutRedirectUri,
                    RedirectUri = redirectUri,
                    Notifications = new OpenIdConnectAuthenticationNotifications
                    {
                        SecurityTokenValidated = context =>
                        {
                            context.Response.Redirect("/members/logon");
                            return Task.FromResult(0);
                        },
                        AuthenticationFailed = context =>
                        {
                            if (context.Exception.Message.StartsWith("OICE_20004") || context.Exception.Message.Contains("IDX10311"))
                            {
                                context.SkipToNextMiddleware();
                                context.Response.Redirect("/members/logon");
                                return Task.FromResult(0);
                            }

                            return Task.FromResult(0);
                        }
                    }
                });
        }
```

Thanks,

Answer (score 4):

> > how to redirect to a custom page after successful login

In AccountController , try to modify the callback redirect url:

```
    public void SignIn()
    {
        // Send an OpenID Connect sign-in request.
        if (!Request.IsAuthenticated)
        {
            HttpContext.GetOwinContext().Authentication.Challenge(new AuthenticationProperties { RedirectUri = "/home/about" }, OpenIdConnectAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationType);
        }
    }
```

use /controllerName/actionName .After OWIN has examined the token and extracted the necessary details, the user is then redirected to your specified URL.

Comment: Do you know why Azure AD can ignore redirect URL? For some reasons my redirect uri gets ignored and Azure redirects me back to login page.

Comment: @Vnuuk , not sure what is your scenario ,click [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/32518873/5751404) and check whether the explanation is helpful to you .

Comment: It gets failed during call of AcquireTokenByAuthorizationCode

Comment: @Vnuuk,without enough information(code/error message) , i can't confirm where cause your error , you'd better start a new thread to describe related details .

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, check if Uri is same at code level and azure level, then check if you are using hash in url, if you are using then remove it as azure does not consider anything after #. Keep in mind after redirecting it will again follow the path. app.modules.ts >> app.components.ts >> and so on... Usually we give application uri without any path to azure you can add a check in app.components.ts if you are pre logged in or not and then decide to redirect to home or login.