# Microsoft Authentication doesn't recognize redirect url property

Tags: c#, asp.net, authentication, azure-active-directory, microsoft-account

I have a problem with my asp .net webapp Im developing right now. I added the possibilty to login with a microsoft account. But I have the problem, that it doesn't take my custom redirect url. In my Azure Ad application the redirect url is configured to /Profile, but the request redirect url it gets from my login button is everytime /signin-microsoft

My Authentication in my startup.cs looks like this

```
services.AddAuthentication("Cookies")
                .AddCookie(opt =>
                {
                    opt.Cookie.Name = "AuthCookie";

                })
                .AddMicrosoftAccount(opt => {
                    opt.SignInScheme = "Cookies";
                    opt.AuthorizationEndpoint = _configuration["AzureAd:AuthorizationEndpoint"];
                    opt.TokenEndpoint = _configuration["AzureAd:TokenEndpoint"];
                    opt.ClientId = _configuration["AzureAd:ClientId"];
                    opt.ClientSecret = _configuration["AzureAd:ClientSecret"];

                });
```

I dont know if this is important but my used options in applicationsettings are:

```
"AzureAd": {
    "ClientId": "<clientId>",
    "ClientSecret": "<clientSecret>",
    "AuthorizationEndpoint":"https://login.microsoftonline.com/<tenantId>/oauth2/v2.0/authorize",
    "TokenEndpoint": "https://login.microsoftonline.com/<tenantId>/oauth2/v2.0/token"
  }
```

Ofc i entered the correct IDs in this

My Login Controller:

```
[HttpGet("microsoft")]
        public async Task<ActionResult>Login(string RedirectUri)
        {
            AuthenticationProperties props = new AuthenticationProperties
            {
                RedirectUri = RedirectUri
            };
            return Challenge(props, MicrosoftAccountDefaults.AuthenticationScheme);
        }
```

And my login button:

```
<NotAuthorized>
   <li class="nav-item">
       <a class="nav-link" href="Login/microsoft?RedirectUri=/Profile">
            Login
       </a>
   </li>
</NotAuthorized>
```

As you can see the Redirect paramenter should be /profile and I set it also in the Authentication Properties to this value, but when i click the login button the url is always:
[https://login.microsoftonline.com/%5C\](https://login.microsoftonline.com/%5C%5C)<tenantId>/oauth2/v2.0/authorize...&**redirect_uri=https%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A5000%2Fsignin-microsoft**&...

So why doesnt it take /Profile as redirect Url?

It is expected that the redirect uri parameter is localhost:5000/Profile

Answer (score 0):

***I tried to reproduce the same in my environment.***

Make sure to use the following in the order in startup.cs

```
  app.UseAuthentication();
    //app.UseIdentityServer();
         app.UseAuthorization();
```

[image]

When I configure it the other way:

```
     app.UseAuthorization();    
app.UseAuthentication();
//app.UseIdentityServer();
```

I was continuously redirected to the Microsoft login page even after signing in.

[image]

Make sure  the redirect must have the below format:
***pattern: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/");***
i.e;

```
RedirectUri = "/home/about"
```

Or

```
RedirectUri = "/home/profile"
```

Below is the result ,if action part is directly requested in browser.
[image]

***Always recheck and set the redirects in the portal such that it matches the redirects in your code.***

[image]

In **startup.cs** , include the scopes required for the operations.

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {
       …..
services.AddAuthentication(options =>
{
    options.DefaultChallengeScheme = MicrosoftAccountDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
    options.DefaultScheme = CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
})
.AddCookie(option =>
{
    option.Cookie.Name = ".myAuth"; //optional setting
})
.AddMicrosoftAccount(microsoftOptions =>
{
                o.ClientId = Configuration["microsoftaccount:clientid"];
                o.ClientSecret = Configuration["microsoftaccount:clientsecret"];
                o.SaveTokens = true;
                o.Scope.Add("offline_access profile ");
                o.CallbackPath ("/signin-oidc"); //microsoft-signin
                o.Events = new OAuthEvents()
                {
                    OnRemoteFailure = HandleOnRemoteFailure
                };
            })
         …..

}
```

***The scopes for delegated Api permissions  required must be granted admin consent .***

[image]

***Then the user is authenticated successfully***

[image]

***If the user is authenticated , then only it is redirected to the specified redirect page/uri.***

[image]

***Reference :*** [How to redirect to particular page after Azure AD Login? - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43060799/how-to-redirect-to-particular-page-after-azure-ad-login)